# How to stream a live channel

Tags: streaming, video

First of all let me make this clear I'm not asking for instruction here but I just wish to ask for some information since I was googling for over a week and felt that I will never get any answer to my questions.

I know that this might not even be the right place to ask about this but at least if I can get any thing from anyone of you to point me to the right place to find out about what I'm trying to do.

I see a site like this http://tv.yoursn0w.com which they can stream a live channel from television and I wonder how they can stream this live

I mean are they using some kind of TV-Tuner? because from what I learned TV-Turner can only stream one channel at the time from TV-PC so if they have this much channels are they going to have like 100 computers and TV to do so? or how can they do it.

Please if anyone can point me to the right place.

Thanks for the answer I'm satisfy here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would require many Tv Tuners, some PVR's allow you to record 1 station and view another but this is only because the PVR has 2 tuners (its often a selling point).
So in theory you would require a TV tuner per channel (frequency) if you where to allow users to view all stations at once.

Some digital stations will broadcast many channels on the same carrier frequency however, this allows you to view all stations on that frequency at once.

At least that my knowledge of free to air broadcast, cable i dont know sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the great information at least clarify me some of my curiosity that something can be done.